# Reading and writing BMP files in C memory error

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, fread

I am attempting to write a program to invert the color of an image. My problem is when I try to read from the DIB header in my BMP file.

When I try to get the file header size and use fread(dib.fileheader, 4,1,fp); . I get an error that says "The memory could not be written". I have attached it for further clarification.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


 struct BMP {
char filetype[2]; // must be BM, must check if BM
unsigned int filesize;
short        reserved1;
short        reserved2;
unsigned int dataoffset;

};

    struct DIB {
unsigned int  fileheader;
unsigned int headersize;
int          width;
int          height;
short        planes;
short        bitsperpixel;  /* we only support the value 24 here */
unsigned int compression;   /* we do not support compression */
unsigned int bitmapsize;
int          horizontalres;
int          verticalres;
unsigned int numcolors;
unsigned int importantcolors
  };
    struct pixel {
int val;
char * def;
struct listitem * next;
  };


 void invertImage(char fileName[]){

  struct BMP bmp;
  struct DIB dib;


     FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");

//FileType
 fread(bmp.filetype, 1,2,fp);
  printf("Value is %c\n", bmp.filetype[1]);

   //Check if file format is BM
  if(bmp.filetype[0] != 'B' && bmp.filetype[1] !='M'){
   printf("Wrong format");
  }
    //Size of the file in bytes
    fread(bmp.filesize, 4,1,fp);
    printf("Value is %d\n", bmp.filesize);
    //Go to dataoffset
    fseek(fp,10,SEEK_CUR);

    fread(bmp.dataoffset, 4,1,fp);
    printf("Offset is %d\n", bmp.dataoffset);


    fread(dib.fileheader, 4,1,fp);
    printf("File header is %d bytes\n", dib.fileheader);


    fclose(fp);

    }

   int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){

   printf("Program name %s\n", argv[0]);


   if( strcmp(argv[1],"-invert") == 0) {
  printf("Invert\n");
  printf("File name is %s\n", argv[2] );

  invertImage(argv[2]);

  }

   else {
  printf("Greyscale\n");
  //greyScaleImage();
   }

  return 0;

    }
```

Also here is the output to my program.

[image]

Comment: Please compile with **all warnings enabled**. You should consider all warnings from C compiler as **errors**. If you're unable to fix a warning, you can ask about that then.

Comment: Also do note that your code relies on `unsigned int` being 32 bits wide.

Comment: Also, for [MCVE](mcve), please remove all unnecessary code in the image and if possible, format the code so that it is indented nicely. Now half the lines of code are not even actually used before the crash.

Comment: Okay, I will keep that in mind. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fread` expects a pointer to memory to write the file contents. So you need to give it the address of `dib.fileheader`

```
fread( &dib.fileheader, sizeof(dib.fileheader),1,fp );
printf("File header is %d bytes\n", dib.fileheader);
```

It's complaining because it's interpreting whatever is in `dib.fileheader` as the address to write to, which may or may not be valid for your program.

Note that the following is ok as it stands because `bmp.filetype` is already a pointer to char - it's a char[]

```
fread(bmp.filetype, 1,2,fp);
printf("Value is %c\n", bmp.filetype[1]);
```

To make it a bit more general, you could write

```
fread(bmp.filetype, sizeof(bmp.filetype), 1, fp);
printf("Value is %c\n", bmp.filetype[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compile your code. You must make some change in your code.

```
fread(bmp.filesize, 4,1,fp);  --- > fread(&bmp.filesize, 4,1,fp);
fread(bmp.dataoffset, 4,1,fp); --- > fread(&bmp.dataoffset, 4,1,fp);
fread(dib.fileheader, 4,1,fp); --- > fread(&dib.fileheader, 4,1,fp);
declare the function : void invertImage(char fileName[]);
```

[image]